# Issue with gradient background height and 100% html and body height

Tags: html, css, height

I have 100% height set on my HTML and body tags so that I can use relative units in my element heights without needing absolute valued heights in a parent element. That's all well and good, but it messes with the gradient background I have set on my body tag.

Some mockup code:

```
<div class="a">stuff</div>
<div class="b">stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff </div>
```

CSS:

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;background:linear-gradient(#400040,#FFF)}
.a{background:#F00;height:100%;width:30%;display:inline-block;}
.b{background:#00F;height:100%;width:30%;display:inline-block;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Kp3/1/)

If I don't have the 100% height on the HTML and body tags, the gradient will end at the bottom of the page, no matter how long or short. This is what I want to have, but I can't seem to find a solution that allows me to do both of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options,

1.Have the gradient fixed so that it remains the same as the page scrolls,

add `background-attachment:fixed;`

http://jsfiddle.net/v53mG/

2.Have the gradient scroll as the page scrolls

need to wrap contents of body inside a div and set the gradient to that div, also 100% height and remove margins of body

**css**

```
.bg-wrapper{
    background:linear-gradient(#400040,#FFF);
    height:100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class="a">stuff</div>
<div class="b">stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff ... </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v53mG/1/

Comment: The thing is that I want to have the background stretched, so that on a longer page, the end of the gradient isn't just a solid colour once more. As for the fixed positioning, again, it's not what I'm looking for, but I suppose if there is no other choice, I might do it. That, or try some other background instead.

Comment: Okay, I've made a bit of progress. I've modified your suggestion a little. I added the wrapper and added the 100% height to it and the body, then remove the 100% height from the HTML, and put the background css on it. What I've noticed now though is that adding that wrapper has broken the layout of the page, sending my divs all on to their own lines. I'll have to play around with this some more, but for now, I think you answered the original question.

Comment: @user3226844 thanks, indeed if you remove the `height:100%` from html and body the `bg-wrapper` will have the correct height and the gradient will be distributed evenly i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/bDF7U/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution that may work for you.

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/t2Kp3/2/)**

It looks like the issue is how the elements are wrapping since they have `display:inline-block;`, one solution is to give them `display:block` and `float: left`.

CSS:

```
body div {float: left;}

.a{
  //other styles
  display:block;
 }

.b{
  //other styles
  display:block;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant to the issue. The the gradient height issue remains, and the div display property must be inline-block, as that is how the site is laid out. The float is also irrelevant to the issue here, I'm afraid.

Comment: I must have not understood the issue properly, what exactly are you wanting to happen that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This not really possible to keep both things.
When you put

> body{height:100%;}

you force body to take 100% of the html tag which is the size of your screen. That mean the body can't strecth to fit the other divs.